# How do you manipulate both the START and END of an instanced point distribute in geometry nodes?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair, geometry-nodes

[image]
I am essentially trying to create something like this, where the fibers have a centrally located starting point, and all radiate outward to the periphery of the object. Preferably these instanced points will be curves that are animatable, such that they appear like wavy hair.
So far, I have used geometry nodes to create point distribute, but I don't know how to orient these in an outward radial pattern like the image.
I have also tried using the old particle system for hair and "brushing" the hair to face a certain direction, but this is too destructive; it seems like there should be a creative procedural method for this, I just can't find any in my deep searches on the internet.
appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: i am not sure whether this is possible at all with geometry nodes right now because we cannot do things like "loop" as animation nodes or sverchok is capable of. And neither for mesh lines nor for curves we can use attributes for start/end points so.... :(

Comment: I would use a turbulence force field. … “old particle system hair”?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I wouldn't necessarily recommend solving this with Geometry Nodes, the question is still kind of intriguing.

One possible answer could look like this:

[image: Result 231089]

Of course, the solution is not particularly performant, but that is exactly why GNs might not be the optimal solution here...

Since the question is already a bit older, I'll leave it as it is for now.
But if there is interest and I find the time, I will be happy to go into detail and supplement this answer.

Here is the Node Group overview:

[image: GN 231089]

And here is the blend file:

[image]