# How to make a luminous fiber optic bundle?

Tags: animation, particles, geometry-nodes

I want to use Geometry Nodes to create a bundle of glowing fiber optic strands.

What are my options here?

[image]

[Source](https://adobe.ly/3JYuEUl)

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Blender.Stackexchange. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask     Try to be more specific on what you actually want help with.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: the hard part is the particles rotating on the top, maybe try with a curve, give it a Force Field physics, Type > Force, Shape > Curve, create an emitter and also some Turbulence force fields?

Comment: @moonboots ...i have an answer to this question, but i cannot post it here, because it is closed. sorry

Comment: so what is your solution?

Comment: @moonboots I would be happy to provide an answer with image and blend file on a reopened question.

Comment: @moonboots maybe vote for reopening the question? *hint hint hint* Go, I want to see how *quellenform* did the bending of the fibers ;-)

Comment: @Blunder I did  ;)  but what happens if BlenderMe edit his question? Will it not reopen?

Comment: I don't know how to reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to instantiate multiple curves along a circle, and randomly offset (and animate) the endpoints of the instances.

All you have to do is to place two circles on top of each other, and use the points of the upper circle as positions for the endpoints of your curves instantiated on the lower circle.

Depending on how you additionally change the curves, the bundling of the fibers will change accordingly.

The animation of the endpoints can be solved in different ways. In this example I simply use a sine curve for an up and down movement, but here you can extend as you like.

[image]

Here is an overview of the Node Group:

[image]

And here the blend file:

[image]

Maybe this question/answer is also interesting or a clue for you:
[How do you manipulate both the START and END of an instanced point distribute in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231089/)

In this example, the upper plane is additionally curved, but the distribution of the points is not along a circle line.

---

**Update**

Since the question just came up in the comments: *"How to use a rectangular shape instead of a circular shape?"*

Actually, this would only require exchanging the curve for the *Cross Section*.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: What if I want to change the form to rectangle? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlRx9.jpg

Comment: @MuhammedSiracOkan Interesting question, I have added the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

I would take a different approach and use a hair particle system, and then you can use hair dynamics and wind and such.

I've marked all of the particle system settings I made a change to (I think)

[image]

There's also a *Viewport Steps* option you can tweak to get better results in the viewport.  Typically in a production scenario I'd leave this as low as possible for performance reasons.

[image]

For this still shot I used a tiny bit of gravity "used for growing", you'd have to mess with this for animation, I'm guessing.

Here's a shader, it needs a little work.  I just chopped off the top of a UV sphere for the emitter.

[image]

Comment: unable to get curve at the top with the settings.

Comment: Oh there's also a viewport panel where you can turn the steps up, but with these settings a render should look right