# Geometry Node : Rotate instances like the shape of grass clump

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to have some grass instanced on a plane and then I want them to bend like a clump of grass. That means they will lie down at the border but will stand up at center.

Example of the concept is like this.

[image]

I don't understand how should I set up the rotation. I think normal will play some role, but I am missing some concept about it.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe try stacking objects with geometry nodes modifiers? Like make one sphere or sphere like object, give a GN graph with the grass blades scattered on it, the normals of that sphere object will inherently make the grass "spawn" like that, then create a plane with a different GN graph that just scatters those spheres on it's face.

Comment: But that will also displace the grass's roots. I don't want that.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259382/145249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These ideas might be a good starting point for you:

### Variant 1

[image]

[image]

This variant is a little more clearly structured and provides a cleaner result:

Here I just use a circle as a base, on which I distribute the points.

Then I instantiate curves there and capture their position to the center with the node `Capture Attribute`.

Then I change the position of the individual curve points using this previously captured value and their position along the curve.

### Variant 2

This variant is also not uninteresting, but is a little strange. ...but could still be helpful/educational.

[image]

[image]

Here I first create a sphere as a base, which I scale strongly in height.

Then I distribute points on the upper half, and set their Z-position to 0.

Next, I instantiate the curves at these points and "bend" their positions outward according to their Z-position.

[image]

Comment: I especially like the bit where you set the curve's direction with a non-existent sphere. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts I can guess you see something here that I might have missed, right? ;-)